# Timer won't start after stop

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer

In my application I'm using two `Timer`, each `Timer` use a `BackgroundWorker`. Here the declaration:

```
DispatcherTimer timer1 = new DispatcherTimer(); 
DispatcherTimer timer2 = new DispatcherTimer(); 
BackgroundWorker worker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
BackgroundWorker worker2= new BackgroundWorker();
```

I using `timer1` for perform an heavy method with a `BackgroundWorker` and `timer2` for execute another `BackgroundWorker` that check the content of a file.

In this way  I assign the event to `BackgroundWorkers`:

```
worker1.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
worker1.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
worker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
worker2.DoWork += worker_DoWork2;
worker2.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted2;
worker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

Now `timer1` have a range of `15 minutes` so the `BackgroundWorker` execute the heavy method each 15 minutes. And `timer2` have a range of `1 second`. With the `timer1` all working good, but the problems are coming when I've added the `timer2`.

As I said before this timer allow me to start a method that read a file through the `worker2`, this file have a property, if this property change I need to perform some special activity. Until here no problem.

What I did is the following:

```
//This method is called by MainWindow
public ReadFile()
{
    //before this I already assigned to timer1 the tick event and start
    timer2.Tick -= new EventHandler(Event_Tick);
    timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(Event_Tick);
    timer2.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    timer2.Start();
}
```

This is the `Tick` event associated to `timer2`

```
private void Event_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!worker1.IsBusy) //I skip the reading, worker1 is busy
     {
         timer1.Stop(); //stop the first timer
         worker2.RunWorkerAsync();
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("worker1 is busy!");
     }
 }
```

I don't need to add here the `DoWork`, is just a parsing of a file, very useless for the question. When `worker2` complete the task I did this:

```
 private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted2(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     timer1.Start();
     ReadFile();
}
```

How you can see I start the `timer1` again, and execute again the `ReadFile` method. Now if `timer1` has reached the interval, so `15 minutes` has passed, should execute the `timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Heavy_Tick);` that execute the `DoWork` to `worker1`. But the `timer1` never start.

I can't figure out to this, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't see where you are starting your worker 1. my guess is, your trouble is caused by this: `if (!worker1.IsBusy)  {  timer1.Stop();`
which is executed every minute. If you do not start worker1 before the next check, timer1 will be stopped again,

Comment: @LocEngineer I wrote in the question that I start the `timer1` before calling `ReadFile`, so trust me, I put also a breakpoint and the `timer1.Start()` is called. Yes I though the same, but I cannot manage to a fix unfortunately.

Comment: Calling `ReadFile` is one thing but `ReadFile`does not start you backgroundWorker `worker1`, does it? And _that_ is what is checked for being busy.

Comment: @LocEngineer Exactly, `ReadFile` only start the `timer2`, in the `Tick` event how you can see in the question I check if the `worker1` (that can be started from `timer1`) is busy, if yes, I skip the reading, also I stop the `timer1` and execute the BackgroundWorker `worker2`

Comment: Yes. And `timer1`has an interval of 15 minutes, right? So before it ticks, `timer2` will have stopped `timer1` again 15 times...

Comment: @LocEngineer 15 times? I tried also to put 1 minutes to `timer1` and this doesn't start.

Comment: Set it to 10 milliseconds or so. If that solves the issue then you know it is caused by timer1 simply starting the background worker too late.

Comment: @LocEngineer ok if I set `timer1` to 10 ms I get `Console.WriteLine("worker1 is busy!");` but the problem still persist to 15 minutes :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I get it!
You want to execute `worker1` every 15 minutes and `worker2` every second but only when `worker1` is not busy. Your problem is this here:

```
if (!worker1.IsBusy) //I skip the reading, worker1 is busy
 {
     timer1.Stop(); //stop the first timer
     worker2.RunWorkerAsync();
 }
```

and this:

```
public ReadFile()
{
    //before this I already assigned to timer1 the tick event and start
    timer2.Tick -= new EventHandler(Event_Tick);
    timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(Event_Tick);
    timer2.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    timer2.Start();
}
```

Set both timer intervals and tick event handlers during startup, e.g. `Form_Load()`or at the beginning of `Main()`. Start them there too. You should not have to **stop** any timer at all! 
By setting the interval, all you have to do is handle the `Tick()` event. Remove your `.Start()` and `Stop()` calls from your `WorkerCompleted`and `Tick` methods and you should do fine.

Comment: Okay I removed Stop and Start and seems working nice, so I guess using only `.IsBusy` I resolve all these problems right? Actually the test is okay, any suggestion? Thanks for this :)

Comment: Exactly. Using `.IsBusy` should suffice. By starting and stopping your timers all over, you are messing up the intervals, hence the erratic behaviour. :-)

Comment: Okay it seems to work well. I have only one question: Suppose that after checking if `worker1` is busy I using `worker2`, in the same moment, however, `worker1` starts from `timer1`; in `worker2` I need to use `worker1` (that is busy), at this point should be generated an exception that says worker1 is busy , you agree with me? There may be such a thing? You might like to manage?

Comment: That I don't quite understand. You say that `worker1` performs "heavy" stuff which you want to perform only every 15 minutes. Now you say that `worker2`, which fires every second, needs to use `worker1` as well? Or does it only need to access the same file `worker1`also accesses? In the latter case, I would simply add another `.IsBusy` check in `worker2` with `Thread.Sleep(50)`, that will let the worker continue once the file is no longer blocked. If you really need `worker1`from within `worker2` though you might have a general design problem.

Answer (score 0):

So a lot could be going on here but you should make sure that:

1. You timer isn't storing it's old progress and you are checking for a certain length of time before stopping. This will automatically cause the timer to stop when restarting.
2. The timer.stop() function is not disposing your object to an un-restart-able state.
3. You aren't accessing the timer variable through some pointer that is maintain a stopped value. (Unlikely but annoying when it happens)

I'd personally consider just pausing the timer and resetting the progress, instead of fully stopping it since this is causing issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I put a breakpoint on the `timer1.Start()` inside the ` worker_RunWorkerCompleted2` event and I see the `15 minutes` correctly, so I think that the object isn't disposed when I called `.Stop`, this is good 'cause the timer still has all the event assigned. Anyway, I cannot find any `.Pause` method, I searched a lot on the web and doesn't found nothing.